# Regex not capturing date

Tags: c#, regex, date

I have a regex that works fine currently.  But now I want to add on to it to capture dates.

Current regex:

```
(?<GeneralHelp>^/help\s*)?
(?:/client:)
(?<Client>\w*)
(?:(?:\s*/(?<ClientHelp>help))*)*
(?:(?:\s*/)(?<Modules>createHistory)(?:(?:\s*/(?<ModuleHelp>help))*)*)*
```

I added to the end:

```
(?:(?:\s*/)(?<StartDate>^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[. -]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[. -]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$))*)*
(?:(?:\s*/)(?<EndDate>^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[. -]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[. -]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$))*)*
```

Using the below example, it just won't get the dates, but it does match everything else.

```
/client:testClient/createHistory/11-11-2013/11.11.2013
```

This regex is used to break up the `Main` one string in the string array parameter from a console app.  No one on my team in "fluent" in regex, nor do we have time to become fluent.  We work with what we can and this addition is something I thought of today that may have with bigger problems what we have with our project and we are running low on time.  So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should add some example data where the regular expression is applied to. Also is it intentional that you didn't escape `.` and `-` inside `[. -]`? As far as I know, these should still be interpreted, so `.`  will match any character, not just periods.

Comment: @Mario: na, [. -] means "match ., space or -". since the "-" is last in the character class there's no problem with unintentional ranges being matched.

Comment: @Mario: inside square brackets, `.` is just a dot and `-` just a hyphen if it's right next to a bracket. @Kendra: is there a reason you use non selective brackets on `(?:\s*/)`?

Comment: Okay, knew about the `-`, but wasn't sure about the `.`. It would be rather pointless to be honest though.

Comment: @Kendra: `(?<StartDate>[^/]+)/(?<EndDate>.+$)` wouldn't fit your needs?

Comment: @Robin I didn't create the original regex.  I just wanted to added to it for new functionality.  But the example to apply the regex to is at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @KendraBall I suggest you learn some regex rather than blindly using it from other people, as you'd have spotted some pretty glaring errors in it already.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `^` in your regex means "start of string", that is you only want to match a date at the start of the string (which is not true for you). So remove it. Same with "$" which means "end of string".

Secondly, `[0|1]` means "match characters 0, | or 1". You probably want `[01]` meaning "match characters 0 or 1".

Thirdly, you have an extra closing bracket with an unmatched opening bracket in both your regexes.

Fourthly as a general style point, `[0]` is the same as `0` so the square brackets are redundant here.

So your (not quite!) "fixed" regex is:

```
(?:(?:\s*/)(?<StartDate>(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[. -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[. -]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})))*
(?:(?:\s*/)(?<EndDate>(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[. -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[. -]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})))*
```

However, this will *not* match your test string because of the extra "/testModule" in the string which is not in your working regex anywhere.
You could modify your original regex to allow extra slashes in between the two parts of regex?

```
<original regex>
(?:/[^/]+)*   # <-- for the /testModule and any other similar tokens that appear in between
<date regex>
```

Also as a general point

- you have a few occurences `(?:(?:regex)*)*`. I am not sure what the point is of doubling the outer `*` besides making the regex parser work much harder than it should for no good reason (the outer `(?: )*` is redundant here).
- there is no point doing `(?:/\s*)` as you are not doing anything with the brackets, so just do `/\s*`
- same with things like `(?:/client:)`. Why have non-capturing brackets if you are not doing anything with them. `/client:` will do.
- `(?:regex)*` means "match 0 to infinity occurences of `regex`". With things like `(?:\s*/(?<ClientHelp>help))*`, do you *really* expect this to occur infinitely many times in your string, or will it appear just once or not at all? Consider replacing `*` with `?` which means "match 0 or 1 occurences" (if you know that that token will appear either once or not at all), or replace it with (say) `{0, 100}` if you know that that token will appear at *most* 100 times (and at least 0 times). This can improve performance.

So I recommend changing your regex like this:

```
(?<GeneralHelp>^/help\s*)?
/client:
(?<Client>\w*)
(?:\s*/(?<ClientHelp>help))*
(?:\s*/(?<Modules>createHistory)(?:\s*/(?<ModuleHelp>help))*)*
(?:/[^/]+)*
(?:\s*/(?<StartDate>(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[. -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[. -]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})))*
(?:\s*/(?<EndDate>(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[. -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[. -]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})))*
```

You can fiddle around with your regex at [regexr](http://regexr.com?384r4) where I've created an example with your regex/test string. (Edit: the < and > in the regex seem to have been changed to < and > in regexr so the link won't work unless you copy/paste the regex I've written directly)

Comment: Nice pretty extensive answer!

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to be capturing the dates.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". If you copy/paste this regex into regexr with your test string, the groups are captured as expected. Perhaps you are doing something wrong in your actual implementation of the regex (calling the wrong function, or not escaping some special characters, etc). Updating the original question with further details could help.

Comment: Besides the fact that the dates are not being captured on regex testers online, I couldn't get it to capture the dates in my code which only breaks up the only string in the string array argument passed in by a console app.

Comment: As mentioned, copy-paste the regex from the post into regexr, and it works (you can't use the link I provided directly because it converts the < and > to &lt; and &gt;). There must be an error happening on the "string in the string array argument passed in by a console app" (so are you using `grep` or `sed` or something? Can you give the command/code you are using to submit the regex?)

Comment: I physcially changed the &lt to < and I also copied and pasted.  But when I hover over the text, it found 13 groups but out of those groups, only 2, the orginial two, client and modules, matched.  If you add in the "help"s, they match too.  
And the command I give to the console is exactly the example above.  And I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure these two last fields are dates, you could simply add something like

```
(?<StartDate>(?:\d+[. -]?){3})/(?<EndDate>.*)$
```

(or even `(?<StartDate>[^/]+)/(?<EndDate>.+)$` if your cases are all in the same pattern and it fits your needs).

Also as already pointed out by mathematical.coffee, the first regex can be improved.